# Terminal printing over JavaFX application on Raspberry

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hi guys I'm new to Raspberry coding, for my three year thesis I'm writing a twitter wall application in javafx to be runned on a Raspberry Pi Model B+ v1.2.

I programmed it in eclipse neon under windows 10 and everything works correctly there, but when i moved the .jar on the raspberry initially it wasn't working at all. After a bit of googling i finally managed to make it work, i was on Raspbian Stretch with Desktop at that time and I only installed Gluon JavaFX Embedded SDK on my raspberry. After that the application started to run, a bit lagging and there was a problem with the input devices (which for me isn't really a problem because my app doesn't need any input from the user). The major issue is that whenever the app prints something on the terminal it shows up over the javafx app covering it.

After that i tried to install Raspbian Stretch Lite and after some steps i managed to make the app works, but with the same issue.
To make it works on Raspbian Stretch Lite i installed jdk8, gluon javafx sdk and xwindows (via sudo apt install xorg libgtk2.0-0).

I make a video of it to show you clearly what is the problem: (you can skip to 1 minute to see the issue)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EyvdpLuLnGwV3xrvgCqBU8e5T3go3-up

Hope someone can help me, thanks!